# img float:right; Div overflow:autoI

Tags: css, image, css-float, overflow, auto

I want to decorate a text with an img at the right border,
this is my code

```
<img width="276" height="183" style="float:right; margin: 0em 0em 0.5em 0em;" src="myimg.jpg">
</img>
<div style="overflow:auto; widt:300em; margin:0em 0em 0.5em 0em;">
 <h3>MyTitle</h3>
 <p>MyText</p>
 <p>MyText2</p>
 <p>MyText3</p>
</div>
```

The img appears at the right border, as intended. Alas the div apears beyond the img, but as intended at the left border.
What is wrong? Should I in the div the widt-property like in the img in an own statement?
Is correct to start with the img? I thought so because then the float-property is first and the HTML-compiler get these property in an order that makes sense.
htms

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and the behaviour of the `div` is correct.

BUT the `div` does not appear beyond the image but rather on the left side of the image.

To you it just seems to be beyond because you gave the `div`an extremly witdh (more than 4000px). Explanation: if an element has more width than there is space it jumps to the next 'line/space' beyond the floated element.

I prepared the code so you can see how it works. Just change the with from the browser window so you can see how the div is on left side and when/how it jumps below.

If starting with the image cannot be answered on the prepared information. It depends how you want to layout the element group.

```html
            <img width="276" height="183" style="float:right; margin: 0em 0em 0.5em 0em;" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
        
            <div style="overflow:auto; width:350px; margin:0em 0em 0.5em 0em; border: 1px dotted red">
                <h3>MyTitle</h3>
                <p><b>Make example full width to see how the div is place at the right side of the image.</b></p>
                <p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie.
                Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, 
                musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular.</p>
                <p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie.
                Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, 
                musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular.</p>
                <p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie.
                Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, 
                musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular.</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hi Brebber, I thank you and will try out your code and suggestion.

Comment: Hi Brebber, I tried out your suggestion with my text, whitch contains a ul-element and i have an unwanted line-break, but only in in 1 element, so it was easier to delete a superfluous word in this item, I used your 350px that is enough. I canged all the measurments to px, instead em.

Comment: For a normal text 350px is enough. If the floated text is too wide then the image is higher than the text and this would cause problems with a following paragraph.

Comment: @Lobito `350px` is just an example to demonstrate how it works. You need to adapt the values to your needs in your layout. But think about this: if you have a non boxed element/section the (needed) width changes with the width of the browser window. Same if you are going on different devices like Desktop/Tablett/Mobile. If you whant to make that static you can wrap the code to an wrapper div and advise a fix width to the wrapper. So you can calculate the needed width for your div and image so they are alway in a static realtion to each other.

Comment: Hi Brebber, I'd say the HTML-Compiler needs to know first what to float and later on how, onoverflow:auto.

Comment: Hi Brebber, I got, that 350px is just an example, but a very good one.

Comment: Yes the widt of the page is browserdependant.

Comment: 360px works Firefox, MSEdge and Chrome without Line-break, I'm just now tryingout Opera. To check if IE can, doesn't value the pain, who use IE today?

Comment: Opera does at 360px without line-break, so I don't know the behaviour of IE, because it has always a cross-grained Browser, I suppose that it will not.

Comment: The styling uses the property `float`. That is an very traditional and very old property still introduced in css level 1. It is supported by IE up from Version 4. (See: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Comment: Hello Brebber, indeed my styling is very old and traditional, but I had a very extended website with different issues and different languages, I styled all with floated divs, it always worked well. The site had at the left border a menuband, so I lost a lot of space for the images, which was mostly big maps, therefor I don't understand why I now with less width and smaller images such a lot of problems. How does modern styling look like?

Comment: Traditional styling is not the wrong way. As old school coder your are able to do a design with one `.class`  and two `div's` where young coders needs upt to 10 `.classes` and 20 `div's`. Or the yougsters need 5-10 lines in JS which is done in HTML/CSS in 3 lines of code. Crazy. But sometimes modern methods makes coding indeed easier. Modern technique to style columns use grid framewoks, css property `flexbox` is a easy way depending on your needed structure and now you can use css property `grid` as it is supported by the browsers now.

Comment: Now I understand and I tell you something now I got another Problem: up to now I had to do with giant pictures, so I never ever had the case that the textblock was higher than the img, now I have and indeed I thought about the adaption the HTML-properties in Javascript (hashtag: DOM-Model). Upto 10 classes, for every img- and text-size? I'm not a friend of case-sensitive solution, it complicates life. To presen an image right to a text is generally looked 1 problem and not upto 10, so 1 solution must suffice.

Comment: I also worked with grids, but stopped, because the by that time most used browser, the IE, showed the grid-borders, very ugly! But flexbox to me is unknown, I'll look what it is, if it allows to widen up a certain line and a certain table-box, then this might to be the 1 solution. Thank you for this tip.

Comment: @ Brebber my last comment was erroneous I didn't work with grid, but with tables, with bad results. Now I'll try out your proposal.

Comment: Working with tables is ... indeed not so good today ... and a technique from web's childhood. I started coding just to the time when div technique with css was introduced and tables became outdated. Indeed my first page still had been a table page ... But if responsive is needed: hard work. A really simple grid framework just to start and to study the mechanic is https://simplegrid.io/. Few code. 250 lines only. Traditional mechanic still working with floats. Worldwide most used framework is https://getbootstrap.com. Many prebuild elements, but extreme complex.

Comment: oh yes the simplegrid I found also but in my opinion this https://medium.com/@neernim/how-to-use-css-flexbox-on-nested-divs-6ebc0b63810

Comment: I regret the wasted time, but well one learns from failure more than from success. Now I'll return to DIV and them nesting and flexboxing.

Comment: now I designed in Excel a structure for CSS-Flexbox to represen a row with an image and image-comment I reach from parent (CSS-row) down to grand-child (image and comment) I did not yet this structure code, but I'm almost sure, that this is not the quickest solution, hopfully the results justifys this lot of work, well, the parent-definition one can copy and paste in the HTML-code and each copy adapt. I don't want to blate aparently there's no "quick-solution", but my former chief, a New Yorker said in german "quick and shit". Would you recommend to do any thing at runtime?

Comment: my last Comment was of the Category "quick- and shit" it's not a HTML-Code but a CSS-Stylesheet.

Comment: fortunately I decide to Flexbox-flex-direction, row, this is the default https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox#columns_or_rows, so there is for me nothing to do, except the container for the image and the comment, so there the flexbox-Attribute flex-direction is to set on Column, no problem, this Container is in my structure the Class "child 2", so there is just to do in CSS implement "child 2".flex-direction:column, which can be done directly in the CSS-definition, that's all! What a great relief.

Comment: I'll set the Attribute after having the CSS-Structure defined, then this setting can be done for all the "child 2"-elements at once, while in the definition it is to type in into each container.

Comment: I think this setting is better done at runtime, I use to prepare a website with the "ONLOAD"-method in the body-element of my HTML-definition but this starts a JavaScript-funktion.

Comment: after having "you asked a hole into stomac" as we say in Germany, i's up to time to start the coding.

Comment: @ Brebber, I never have been fond of typing a boring subject, like a data-structure, just because it's boring most error ocure, so I had the idea to develope a stylesheet in which the structur to style a decorated text-block once for ever defined, this require to import this stylesheet to the site-specific stylesheet and to adapt the HTML-file in respect to the used classes and the site-specific stylsheet extend by the definition of the container-class for the decorated paragraph,

Comment: concidering, such a decorated paragraf as a section of the site consisting
of a text-block this can have a title and may consist of p-tags in 
undetermined number, such a text-bof a text-block may have one image 
and an image-comment, or non of this, in the site-specific stylesheet
these absolute inner elements in my structur must related by determin a 
container-class (text-block) and adding the classname "txt" in the HTML-file.
I know this sounds very complicated, but it ensure to work in multiple
site with the same principle, this make lateron the styling easier and faster.

Comment: I'm not decided what to do with the elements between the decorated paragraph that is principaly some thing else, like a hr-tag, head- or foot-block is another business.

Comment: As far as a text-block won't positioned verticaly in relation to the successor or forerunner I can ignore them.

Comment: After this long preface, here the stylesheet, most likly in parts.

Comment: .c {
   class: "row_block_container";
   display: flex; /* this setting schould remain, because it define row_block_container as a container-class             */
   family_level:0;
}

.r {
   class: "row_block";
   display:block; /* if this is set to flex then each row_block-element can threated without affecting the others ! */
   family_level:1;
}

.b {
   class: "text_block";
   display:block; /* this is also a container in the HTML-file the items has mostlikly differen classes
   family_level:2;
}

Comment: .x {
   class: "img_block";
   display:block; /* this is also a container and set on flex the img-block could threated separately if something is wrong */
   flex-direction:column;
   family_level:2;
}

.i {
   class: "img";
   family_level:3;           display:none;
}

.p {
   class: "com";
   display:none;
   family_level:3;
}

q {
  class: "txt"; /* Mentioning this class is the only pupos of this variable, */
}

Comment: Ready, without my header for this file, there I described how to add to an existing CLASS-Attribute the class "txt" and how to import a stylesheet to another.

Comment: Beginners like me will ask these how-to-do

Comment: How to add a CLAS if there ain't this atribute you simply ad in your HTML-file as usualy.

Comment: else you define

Comment: Class="existing clas-definition txt"

Comment: omit to separate the existing definition from "txt"

Comment: omit to separate the existing definition from "txt", the space is enough, more CSS needs not.

Comment: @Lobito Due to the coventions here: that are questions to (an)other problem(s) than the origin of this post is. And to help based on code fragements in the comments is nearly ... not possible. Cause of this I would suggest you open to this new question another post here in Stackoverflow. As I undestand you have concrete problem with a concrete code example. If you prepare that code to a working example in your question me or others will be able to help.

Comment: How to import one stylsheet to another: in our case you add to your site-specific '@import "flexbox_row_definition.css"'. This works if you have both stylsheets in the same carpet, else add to this rule the path of flexbox_row_definition.css". As usual in every program-language you set this import-rule at the very begining.

Comment: I won't open another question, but I know how it is when you found some thing interesting in the web but you don't know how to implement, so I mention these problemsto signal that here we can help.

Comment: oh now I see, the "ain't" well my english is not only from shool but also from the GIs stationed where I grew up they had come from Vietnam wounded to finish their servic in Germany and these guys as far as I learnt from the conversations with them had been in the US from a lower social-level I know that they didn't speak a correct english, but they were for us boys like elder brothers.

Comment: well if the "display: auto" is a problem one can use instead "block" or "normal"

Comment: now I see, why you proposed to ask another question, because I had called my self a beginner, this was a joke!

Comment: Mean while I adapted a site of 5 blocks now it open syntacxerrorfree and I'm playaround with flexbox and there with the colors.